# Can't call Javascript function - scope?

Tags: functions, jquery

I get a method not defined error when trying to call a function loaded with `wp_enqueue_script` from `site.js`.

I'm guessing it's because of scope caused by the jQuery ready wrappers?  How do I get around that?

**site.js** (loaded in `head`)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() { // wait until everything has loaded
    doSomething(); // results in face palm
  });
});
```

**my-script.js** (loaded in footer)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  function doSomething() {
    alert("Time for a coffee break!");
  }
});
```

**functions.php**

```
wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/my-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
// Pass in PHP variables
wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'my_script', localize_post_vars() );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your `doSomething` in the correct namespace, or at least in a namespace. The simplest way would be to put it in the `window` namespace:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    window.doSomething = function() {
        alert("Time for a coffee break!");
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  If I omit `window.`, the function assignment code also works.  Is it defaulting to the `window` namespace in this case?

Comment: Yep, to force the variable to be local you would just add `var` in front of the declaration: `var doSomething = function() { ... };`.